# Unable to get the Content for React Script Editor Webpart in SharePoint Modern Experience using c#

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, script-editor-webpart

We have migrated our site to SharePoint Modern experience from classic. For that we had to replace the Script Editor with the [React Script Editor](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor), as  Script editor is no longer available in modern experience. Now, we are trying to validate the document/page links after migration by fetching the ServerProcessedContent property for all web parts by using **SharePointPnPCoreOnline**:

```
  using (ctx = authMgr.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(siteUrl, userName, password))
  {
    web = ctx.Web;
    //loading sharepoint web instance  
    ctx.Load(web);
    ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    sitePagesList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name = 'ID'/></OrderBy></Query></View>";

    var allItems = sitePagesList.GetItems(query);

    ctx.Load(allItems, eachItem => eachItem.Include(i => i["DisplayName"]));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var i in allItems)
    {

      ctx.Load(i, I => I.File, I => I.DisplayName);
      ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
      file = i.File;
      file.EnsureProperty(x => x.Name);
      var page = ClientSidePage.Load(ctx, file.Name);
      var webParts = page.Controls.FindAll(c => c.Type.Name == "ClientSideWebPart");

      if (webParts != null && webParts.Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (var webpart in webParts)
        {
          try
          {
            clientSideWebPart = (ClientSideWebPart)webpart;
            // This is the property we are trying to get
            JObject jsonObject = clientSideWebPart.ServerProcessedContent;

          }
          catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

We are able to get the value for all other webparts, but for React Script Editor there are no results in the **ServerProcessedContent** property:

```
{"htmlStrings":{},"searchablePlainTexts":{},"imageSources":{},"links":{}}
```

I tried to do it with CSOM but it didn't work either. Am I missing something or is there a different way to get the content for react script editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ServerProcessedContent property of React Script Editor is an empty object. You can verify its value from the workbench:

[image]

BR